# Issues with this css/jquery combo

Tags: jquery, css

Show/hide works perfectly fine.  I can click #business which opens my menu, click outside the element 'html' which closes the menu, or click #business again.

Problem 1:  #business does not revert back to #323232.

Problem 2:  If I click inside of the new menu (#businessmenu) jquery hides it, how can I only hide it by clicking outside of the element or on #business toggle?

JavaScript:

```
$("#business").click(function(event){
    jQuery.fx.off = true;
    $("#businessmenu").toggle("");
    $(this).css("background-color", "#000");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$('html').click(function() {
    $("#businessmenu").hide();
    $("#business").css("background-color", "#323232");
});
```

CSS:

```
header {
  float: left;
  background: #323232;
  width: 98%;
  padding: 0 1%;
  color: #E9F1F4;
}

header a {
  color: #e9f1f4;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
header a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

header #business {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 35px 13px 20px;
}

#businessmenu {
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  width: 220px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 1%;
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  padding: 10px 35px 13px 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="business">Name</a>

<div id="businessmenu">             
    <a href="help.html">Help</a>                
</div>
```

Comment: try setting up a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `stopImmediatePropagation` and `isImmediatePropagationStopped` methods for your `click` events.

As there is more logic rather than just 'togglin', because if you click outside, you're not toggling `#business`, you're just hiding the `#businessmenu`, and forcing a toggle means adding even more logic.

Here is a jsfiddle with your full working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mG5vS/1

For your **1st problem**, I just added an `if` statement inside the click event:

```
$("#business").click(function(e){
    if($("#businessmenu").is(":hidden")) {
        //...do things
        e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //don't hide menu right after showing
    } else {
        hide(); //hide/revert to everything to initial state
    }
});
```

For your **2nd problem**, I added those *stop event propagation* functions like this:

```
$("#businessmenu").click(function(e){
     e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //don't hide when clicking menu links
});

$('html').click(function(e) {
    if(!e.isImmediatePropagationStopped()){ //Hide unless told not to
        hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: There is still a problem with hovering over "#business" after the menu is hidden again. It works when you first load page, but not after a menu has been shown and hidden again...

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use toggle for toggling css classes when your element is clicked

```
$('#business').toggle(function() {
  $(this).addClass('toggled');
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('toggled');
});
```

Now with demo :) http://jsfiddle.net/8CJnV/

Comment: good answer, but in jquery you have toggleClass() so is easier